# How to proper use cover background.image property

Tags: html, css

I have a few `div`s (sections) and I want them to have a `background` spread all over the section.
I have this image `1920x1080 px` and I'm using these properties to display it:

```
#first{
    background-image: url(images/officialWallpaper.jpg);
    background-size:     cover;                      
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to make display the image like `cover` does, but starting from the top of the image so it does't get cropped.

Leaving you my [website](http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/) so you can understand what I mean when I say the top of the image is cropped! (The first section has `cover`, the second `contain` so you can see the difference)

Comment: Is it the first image that has a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** If you just want the top part of the image to display and don't care about the bottom part, just remove the `background-position:center center`.

```css
#first {
  background-image: url(http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/images/officialWallpaper.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-position: center center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" id="first" style="height: 459px;background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
  <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 459px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:** You may use contain and get a result where the whole image is displayed, just a little smaller.

```css
#first {
  background-image: url(http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/images/officialWallpaper.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" id="first" style="height: 459px;background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
  <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 459px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Option 3:** Using fixed,

```css
#first {
  background: url(http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/images/officialWallpaper.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" id="first" style="height: 459px;background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
  <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 459px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed answer, however, yes removing that position property solved mt issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-position: top center` to align the background to the top of viewport.

```
#first{
    background-image: url(images/officialWallpaper.jpg);
    background-size:     cover;                      
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `background-position` to `top left` i.e. `background-position: center center;`

Answer (score 0):

It's the position you want to change...

```
#first {
  background: url("images/officialWallpaper.jpg") top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is some cropping in 1st image, so to solve that use **background-position** as **top** or **top center** and **background-size** to **cover**. Which covers the full viewport height and width.

```
#first{
background-image: url(images/officialWallpaper.jpg);
background-size:     cover;                      
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: top;
}
```